# nginx (has php installed ) proxy_pass specified directory to apache server( with php-fpm) failed

Tags: php, apache, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

Hope someones can give help.
we have two servers here,  one is nginx + php-fpm, another is apache + php-fpm, they are in the same LAN.

In the nginx server we have php site www.xxx.com
And we also have php website pages on apache servers too. 
What we want is , when user  accesss  www.xxx.com/yyy/* the request will be send to apache server , the apache server and its php will handled the request. 
At the same time, the URL  www.xxx.com/yyy/*  shouldn no be changed.

In the nginx server I added configuration in  /etc/nginx/conf.d/xxx.conf like below:

```
location ^~ /yyy/ {
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass http://10.47.127.226:8088/;    //the apache port is 8088
}
```

Then reload the nginx service,
when we access www.xxx.com/yyy/ ,  it can load the page ,  but it can only display txt related information,  No web page format or picture related dispalyed.   (I can confirm the apache and its php is working fine, and I can directly access it normally via  http://10.47.127.226:8088/)

So I am not sure if the request is possible?  if possible, whatelse I can do for nginx ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Is there any reason why you use apache instead of serving everything with nginx?

Comment: Hi Charlotte,  Thanks for your comment.  In fact others designed the system.  So I aslo not sure why they did like this.    But now I have to resolve this problem...

Comment: Have you checked apache's access and error logs?

Comment: Yeah, checked the apache's access and error log,   from the log, only access.log has record,   when I access one time via browser, it will only have  1 access record  /  (access path is root)  ,  it shows code 200.        Seems the nginx didn't transfer request such as  .jss  .cs .jp  to apache .

Comment: As far as I understand the question, you see html as plain text in a browser, so it looks like a trouble with `Content-type` HTTP header. Check HTTP headers which are sent to a client by nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help.  Finally I resolved the question.
The root case is in apache server site.  in the php code, the url php generated without directory /yyy/, but it should have directory /yyy/ in generated url .   The developer added /yyy/to generated php url.  and it worked. 
The nginx proxy configuration is ok.